# Add image view to sub class in Android?

Tags: android

In my sub class I am trying to add an image View:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
```

But it breaks the app. I think it is because of the 'this' param.

Does my class need to extend something? At the minute it extends Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that but you need to provide `this.ApplicationContext` instead of `this`. Alternatively you could derive a View instead of an Activity and use constructor's `Context` argument for the ImageView constructor.